# Removing the space where the title should be for menu Item

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

If I set the `android:title=''` option in my `activity_main_drawer.xml`:

[image]

I get the title displayed.  However I've only got one menu option in there, I dont need a title.  So if I remove that line:

[image]

I end up with a blank space.  How can I get rid of that unnecessary space?

My XML for `activity_main_drawer.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myfolders"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="My Folders"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/systemoptions"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Preferences">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/system_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
                android:title="About" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

The code I use to add items to the menu is a function called setupMenu:

```
 NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    int x = 0;
    while(x < folders.size()) {
        menu.add(R.id.myfolders,Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,folders.get(x++));
    }
    navView.invalidate();
```

Comment: have you tried android:title="@null"? Can't test it at the moment, but maybe a null is interpreted differently?

Answer (score 0):

Menu-Item-Menu-Item may not be the appropriate structure here. If you want the horizontal line to appear above "About" so that it appears as a separate section, use the below code structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:showIn="navigation_view">
....
....
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
           android:id="@+id/about_menu">
        <item android:id="@+id/system_about"
              android:title="About"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_info" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Menu-Group-Item is used here.

Comment: Do I change both @+id/myfolders and @+id/systemoptions to groups? Because If I only change systemoptions, I get the 'My Folders' title above 'About'.  If I change them both to groups, I get the myfolders list (which is dynamically added) and not the systemoptions menu anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the group tag instead of nesting your items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myfolders"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="My Folders" />

    <group
        android:id="@+id/systemoptions"
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:orderInCategory="2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/system_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
            android:title="About" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: For some reason I get the title at the bottom after I've added menu items to `myfolders` dynamically.

Comment: can you add your code where you dynamically add add your items?

Comment: by removing remove `android:orderInCategory="1"` from your item it should put the folders at the top and the dynamically added items below